# Does direct session overwrite utm source from previous session in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

Let's say that a person clicks on an ad on Facebook and lands on a page

> http://www.store.com/product-page?utm_source=ad-agency-name&utm_medium=facebook&utm_content=fruit&utm_campaign=company-name

Than it closes a browser.

Later that day a person visits same page again by writing url directly in browser and purchases a product.

Google Analytics eCommerce tracking code is implemented on thank you page of that store.

Will Google Analytics eCommerce show this transaction's source as '(direct)' or as 'facebook'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will show this as "facebook". Google says that visits are attributed to the last marketing channel (for transaction attribution this is explicitely [stated in the documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1662518?hl=en)  but is also true just for visits).

Direct/Bookmarked visits are not a marketing channel according to Google. If there is already campaign info stored the visit will be attributed to the campaign (so a direct visit in GA is actually a direct visit by someone who has no prior campaign exposure or has deleted his GA cookie).

Btw. this means that campaign conversions will be overcounted at the expense of direct visits, if you need a more realistic picture you would have to look at the multichannel funnels which attribute to the "real" medium, not the marketing channel.

Comment: Thank you Eike! Link to google support page is very insightful.

I asked this question, because I can't figure out why Facebook Ads statistics shows 1 conversion, but in Google Analytics transaction is attributed to "direct" source. I thought that maybe direct visit overwrites previous marketing channel.